# IE 8's invalid procedure call or argument

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, google-maps

i wanna acess the opener's class in child window(created by window.open), 
w3c browser works fine,but it fails in IE 8.
i also tested iframe and it works fine in all browsers.
the purpose of this sample is to reduce google maps loads 
**parent window**

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>

<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&language=cn"></script>
    <script>
        function openIEWin(){
           var TRACK = window.open('child.html?t='+new Date().getTime(),'');
           TRACK.focus()
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body style="background-color:#cfc;" class="abc">
    <button onclick="openIEWin()">New Window</button>
    <!--iframe page can successfully access and invoke the parent window's class-->
    <iframe src="b.html"></iframe>
```

**child window:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body onload="init()">
    <div id='map' style="width:600px;height:480px;"></div>
        <script>
            function init(){
                var google= window.opener.google;
                //cause an error
                var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644);
                var myOptions = {
                  zoom: 8,
                  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
                  center:latlng
                };
                //cause an error
                var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'),myOptions);
            }
        </script>
```

the error message is so typical:
**invalid procedure call or argument**
then i tried IE's window.showModelessDialog,but just met the same error.
so how to fix this problem?
it seems that we can not use new to create instance ?

Answer (score 0):

I guessing this has to do with IE not really supporting passing objects between windows. If the google maps code at any point tries to call JSON.stringify on the config object, then I think this error will be thrown as JSON.stringify is unable to recognize the object as a valid object.

Try moving this code to the opener page, and then call this method from the child page passing the element to display in (`document.getElementById('map')`) as an argument.

Comment: thanks for your help,still dosent work.and the error message means like this: not supported interface.

Comment: i step into the code,and fount the LatLng function is simple:  function Q(a, b, c) {
        a -= 0;
        b -= 0;
        c || (a = Ed(a, -90, 90), b = Fd(b, -180, 180));
        this.Pa = a;
        this.Qa = b
},why ie throws error when running  this code,i cant understand